# Inverted Barcode Reader Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, barcode

I am using an AVCapture: Session, Device, DeviceInput, MetadataOutput and a VideoPreviewLayer in order to scan barcodes. I am having a bit of trouble reading inverted barcodes (white bars on a black background).

I've tried inverting the actual barcode data's byte codes by getting the bytes in the `metadataObjects` from the `captureOutput` method and using `byte = ~byte`. That didn't work out to well as the metadataObject wouldn't properly convert to an NSData object. 
I hoped this would invert the barcode data but it was a mess.

I just don't know what to do, whether I have to pass the image through a filter and then decode the data or what.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
_session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
_device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;

_input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
if (_input) {
    [_session addInput:_input];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

_output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[_session addOutput:_output];


_output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

_prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];

_prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
_prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

[_session startRunning];
```

This is how I'm initializing the `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, `AVCaptureMetadataOutput`, and the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

I'm now trying to implement `GPUImage` framework into my project but I keep getting the `"GPUImage.h" file not` found when I'm trying to import the main header file.

Comment: I've tried inverting the actual barcode data's byte codes by getting the bytes in the metadataObjects from the captureOutput method and using byte = ~byte. That didn't work out to well as the metadataObject wouldn't properly convert to an NSData object. I hoped this would invert the barcode data but it was a mess. I just don't know what to do, whether I have to pass the image through a filter and then decode the data or what.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your comments into your question. To further improve the question, you can use the "edit" link below your post. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @S.L.Barth . I'm very new to Stack Overflow as you might be able to tell ;).

Comment: You're welcome! I feel the question is greatly improved, and hope you'll get an answer.